# Definition of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

The definition of modules confuses me:

$R$ is a ring, then a left $R$ module is an abelian group $V$ together with a multiplication map $$R \times V \to V, (r,v) \to rv$$ satisfies some natural axioms.

So from the definition,is that means $rv \in V$ ? But since $R$ is a ring and $V$is an abelian group, so the product of an element of ring and an element of group is still in that group ??
I know the vector space example, and it is easy to understand that a vector multiply a scalar is still a vector, so how do you explain module?

Comment: It's the same as with vector spaces... It's a "vector" (one wouldn't use that word here) by definition of the multiplication map $R\times V\to V$.

Comment: A module is just like a vector space in this regard. Multiplying by an element $r$ of the ring $R$ maps a module element $v$ to module element $rv$.  Of course that is just notational shorthand.  An abelian group is the same as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module if we let integers "multiply" group elements in the obvious way (repeated addition).

Comment: The product of an element of a field and an element of a group is still in that group??

Comment: @seaturtles:  A vector space is an abelian group under addition, so if you have defined vector space operations, you have defined a special case of module, where the ring is a field.

Comment: @hardmath Compare my wording to OP's wording (and punctuation)...

Comment: @seaturtles: I don't take your point.  What product are you talking about? If you are talking about a group operator product, you are missing the fact that abelian groups are customarily represented additively.  In any case that's the point I'm trying to bring out.  In the OP's Question it seems clear the product is "scalar product"-like, which is the right analogy.

Comment: @hardmath It strikes me as extremely odd that OP is perfectly fine with ring elements multiplying group elements when the ring is a field but not when the ring wasn't a field - whether or not the ring is a field shouldn't matter. I was lampshading that strange fact.

Comment: @seaturtles: I'm with you. It seems odd that it bothers the OP.

Answer (score 2):

There is an operation $\cdot : R\times V \rightarrow V$.  We normally suppress the dot when it is understood that an expression is a product of an element of $R$ (on the left) and an element of $V$ (on the right).  It's just some map with a bunch of properties (which you mention).  This is very similar to a ring "just" being an abelian additive group with an additional operation.

In vector spaces, you have a similar operation receiving a scalar and a vector and producing a vector.  It's just more familiar, so you don't think about it (or you think about it entirely in components).  We even use the language "scalar multiplication" and "vector multiplication" to make this distinction (and "scalar-vector multiplication" when other vector products are floating around and/or we're being pedantic).